# grpc : call was half-closed error

Tags: java, android, grpc, google-cloud-speech

I'm using Google Cloud Platform Speech API.
I'm developing using sample source.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech

almost the same as sample source.
except many start/stop of VoiceRecorder in my app.

I got this error in samsung devices.
I didn't get this error in huawei devices.

> com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState (Preconditions.java:444)
>   io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.sendMessage (ClientCallImpl.java:389)
>   io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall.sendMessage (ForwardingClientCall.java:67)
>   io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$CallToStreamObserverAdapter.onNext (ClientCalls.java:302)
>   com.example.myapp.SpeechService.recognize (SpeechService.java:299)
>   com.example.myapp.MyActivity$1.onVoice (MyActivity.java:152)
>   com.example.myapp.VoiceRecorder$ProcessVoice.run (VoiceRecorder.java:224)

Please help me if you have experienced the same problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The error means you previously called `onCompleted()` but are now calling `onNext()`; that's not allowed.

The code in `SpeechService.java` looks pretty reliable to avoid this sort of problem. My only guess is that you're using the class from multiple threads, but the class is not thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.