# Reason for Java gRPC server "Half-closed without a request"

Tags: grpc, http2, grpc-java

I have a gRPC server using the `grpc-java` library. Sometimes a call to the server is closed with and error status `INTERNAL` which is valued `13`, and the description `Half-closed without a request`.

I found this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358715/grpc-call-was-half-closed-error) that seems similar, but there it was said that the code was calling `onComplete()` before calling `onNext()`, and my endpoint actually works just fine, this error happens very sporadically given the number of calls it responds.

Looking at the implementation of `UnaryServerCallListener` it seems that the only way that something like this could happen is if the `request` received on `onMessage` is null.

```
@Override
      public void onMessage(ReqT request) {
        if (this.request != null) {
          // Safe to close the call, because the application has not yet been invoked
          call.close(
              Status.INTERNAL.withDescription(TOO_MANY_REQUESTS),
              new Metadata());
          canInvoke = false;
          return;
        }

        // We delay calling method.invoke() until onHalfClose() to make sure the client
        // half-closes.
        this.request = request;
      }

      @Override
      public void onHalfClose() {
        if (!canInvoke) {
          return;
        }
        if (request == null) {
          // Safe to close the call, because the application has not yet been invoked
          call.close(
              Status.INTERNAL.withDescription(MISSING_REQUEST),
              new Metadata());
          return;
        }

        method.invoke(request, responseObserver);
        request = null;
        responseObserver.freeze();
        if (wasReady) {
          // Since we are calling invoke in halfClose we have missed the onReady
          // event from the transport so recover it here.
          onReady();
        }
      }
```

What could cause the request to be missing ?

Comment: If the client doesn't call `sendMessage` and just calls `halfClose` after starting the call?

Comment: Agree with San's opinion. For unary RPCs, the service is expected to receive exactly one request. The ServerCallListener can get notified with `halfClosed` before receiving any request message if the client side half-closes the stream (aka, ClientCall) before any requests message is sent. This can happen when the client called `StreamObserver.onComplete()` before `StreamObserver.onNext()`.